# Convert long formula into an ARRAYFORMULA

Tags: excel-formula, google-sheets, array-formulas

Document: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1N4cGw5eUq_3gCJh1w39qVatX9KV1_Hr-AqRHj_nbckA/edit#gid=1770960621

---

### Question

How can I convert the following simple formulas at `Schedule!C20:I29` into a single, simple ARRAYFORMULA at `Schedule!C20`?

```
=Count(Filter(Students!$B$5:$B, Find(C6, Filter(Students!$J$5:$O,Students!$J$4:$O$4 = 'Current Class'!$B$3))))
.
```

NOTE:

- The above code is only a partial solution. I will **substitute** the ARRAYFORMULA version of the code into the correct part of the code at `Current Class!L6`
- The `C6` reference above can take on any cell between `Schedule!C6:I15`. I have named that range `Timetable_Code`. *I thought I could do the following, but I was wrong...*

  `=Arrayformula(Count(Filter(Students!$B$5:$B, Find(Timetable_Code, Filter(Students!$J$5:$O,Students!$J$4:$O$4 = 'Current Class'!$B$3)))))`

### Background

Originally, I created a table that now resides at `1st Version - Current Class!L6`. This tab is only for your reference and will be deleted soon. Each cell has a formula with a slight modification. **This formula works correctly; however, it is a behemoth and would be hard to modify...**

```
=if(COUNTIF(Meta!$B$5:$B, CONCATENATE("=",if(L$5 = "THURSDAY", "TH", if(L$5 = "SUNDAY", "SU", left(L$5,1))), if(left($K6, 2) = "12", 0, left($K6, 1)))), CONCATENATE(if(L$5 = "THURSDAY", "TH", if(L$5 = "SUNDAY", "SU", left(L$5,1))), if(left($K6, 2) = "12", 0, left($K6, 1)), "     ( ", Count(Filter(Students!$B$5:$B, Find(CONCATENATE(if(L$5 = "THURSDAY", "TH", if(L$5 = "SUNDAY", "SU", left(L$5,1))), if(left($K6, 2) = "12", 0, left($K6, 1))), Filter(Students!$J$5:$O,Students!$J$4:$O$4 = $B$3)))), " )") ,"")
.
```

**Pros**

- I don't have to create any helper data.
- All calculations are "in-memory"

**Cons**

- Too large
- Hard to modify

I like the output, but I don't like the cons, so I started to create a more edit-friendly version of the code that I am mostly OK with. This code is located at `Current Class!L6` (and a secondary copy at `Schedule!C33` - it will be deleted.) It has a **single** formula at `Current Class!L6`...

```
=arrayformula(if(COUNTIF(Meta!$B$5:$B, ("=" & Timetable_Code)), (Timetable_Code & "     ( " & Timetable_StudentCount & " )") ,""))
.
```

**Pros**

- Very easy to understand
- Very easy to modify
- No need to copy formula over to other cells

**Cons**

- Two ( 2 ) helper tables were created ( one of which I think is unneeded)

Again, I like the output, but I really don't like the second helper table (`Schedule!C20`). I feel like this table can be eliminated, but I have not been able to figure out how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After getting a good answer from @Sangbok Lee, I decided to break apart each part of the function he gave to me. While doing that I found a highly unlikely connection to some work I did in the Google Sheets last week. A helper column I had in another tab kind of did what Sangbok Lee was trying to do. All I had to do was split that helper column into two columns (1 for the previous final calculation, 1 for) and calculate an additional count column

After reworking both of our formulas, and testing the result, I found a solution that I am even more satisfied with!

```
=arrayformula(if(countif(Meta!$B$5:$B, (Timetable_Code)), (Timetable_Code & "     ( " & vlookup(Timetable_Code, StudentCount_Lookup, 2, false) & " )") ,""))
.
```

**Check out the differences in the [Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1N4cGw5eUq_3gCJh1w39qVatX9KV1_Hr-AqRHj_nbckA/edit#gid=301786419)**

- Look at `1st Version - Current Class!L6` tab for the 1st version
- Look at `Current Class!L6` for the 2nd version
- Look at `Current Class!U6` for the 3rd and final version
- Also look at tab `Meta` and `Schedule` for the differences.

*Note: Green is old data, Red is new data*

Comment: Good idea and I'm glad that you've found the satisfying solution. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use `arrayformula`, here it is. For `Schedule!C20`.

```
=arrayformula((len(concatenate(index(Students!J5:O, , match('Current Class'!$B$3, Students!J4:O4, 0))))-len(substitute(concatenate(index(Students!J5:O, , match('Current Class'!$B$3, Students!J4:O4, 0))),C6:I15,"")))/len(C6:I15))
```

Probably you can use `filter`(as you did before) instead of `index & match` part, but I prefer `index & match` and don't want to dig more. Also you can use **one** help cell to store `filter` or `index & match` result to shorten the formula.

The core idea is from counting occurrences of given character in a string, ie `len(a1) - len(substitute(a1, ...`. You can find many documents about it in the net.

Anyway, if I were you, I'd be satified with the current state. Just lock and hide the help tables or sheets. Nobody cares hidden sheets and if something bad happens, you can revert any change.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It was really helpful. I broke apart your function to understand it, and I found a better solution based on a code snippet I already did previously. It still requires 2 sets of helper data, but the second one has a smaller footprint. Will look at posting my own answer soon